# Wordpress URL rewriting, parameters in URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a Wordpress page that receives a parameter in URL, like :

```
www.test.it/mypage/?param=1
```

and I would like to make it work using

```
www.test.it/mypage/1/
```

What do I have to write in .htaccess to achieve it?

---

Edit: I'm using Apache, the current mod_rewrite rules are these (default Wordpress rules):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Set up rewrites in wp and see how it does it ^_^...

Comment: I already set it... the problem is I don't know how to work with a parameter and make it look like a subdirectory, and only on a specific page.
Wordpress rewrites all the URLs, it's a more generic solution and I'd need a more specific one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_mypage_rule' );

function add_mypage_rule(){
    add_rewrite_tag("%param%", '(\d+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^mypage/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=mypage&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA]
```

For more details

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Try this link

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/

Hope this works

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, maybe because of the pre-existing rules set by Wordpess?

Comment: The second link is very very helpful, +1.
If I work it out I'll post the solution.

Comment: Were you ironic or what? Anyway, just posted it.